# Why moving prawnto to Gemfile gives "Missing Template" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, prawn, prawnto

After [moving gem dependencies to bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183509/why-prawnto-gem-installs-rails-3-x-when-there-is-already-a-rails-2-x) in a 2.3.5 project, why there is an error:

```
  Template is missing

  Missing template .../show.erb in view path app/views
```

when generating a PDF?

PDF can be generated if I put:

```
  require "prawn"
  require "prawnto"
```

in `environment.rb` but I am not sure whether this is *the* fix.